# XOM Parser Element.getAttributeValue() returns null if attribute name has :

Tags: parsing, xom

I have been using XOM parser in a project that is mostly over. The parser is very good and I find it mostly stable. However today I was parsing an XML element with an attribute called "xml:lang"

The getAttributeValue("xml:lang") returned null instead of "English". I could find a work around to get the value by using getAttribute(int location).getValue()

However, it would be better to use the method getAttributeValue because the attribute's location changes for other elements.

I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong or a small bug lies there in the library method.

Answer (score 0):

The `xml:lang` attribute is in a [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/).

To get the value of an attribute in a namespace, use the [`Element.getAttributeValue(String, String)`](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Element.html#getAttributeValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. The first parameter needs to be the local name of the attribute (after the colon), which is `lang` in this case. The second parameter needs to be the URI of the namespace, which is usually [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl) in an ancestor element. The `xml` namespace, however, is built in and always has the namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`.

Therefore, some code like this should do what you want (assuming you have a variable called `element` pointing to your element):

```
String lang = element.getAttributeValue("lang", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");
```